# Anyway to access statusbar menu items from keyboard when app is not in focus?

Tags: swift, macos, statusbar, menubar

I've written a menubar app in swift and am wondering if it's possible to access the app from the keyboard programmatically?

Let's say my app recorded audio from the desktop mic. How would I write my app to have a keyEquivalent to start recording I was in chrome or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately all keyboard events are always sent to the active (frontmost) application but you could define a global hot key (for example with [DDHotKey](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey)) to activate the menubar application.